# Use a global var / singleton to store the auth token sent from client?

Tags: firebase, authentication, singleton

I'm using Firebase as my server and client, and it uses token-based authentication. i only have mobile clients, so basically there's no user session to manage on server, client needs to send a IdToken with every api request.

Per this request:

can I just create a global variable or singleton to store this token in memory, so i can use later in the stack? (instead of passing this idtoken everywhere in the stack)

```
var sess;
app.get('/',function(req,res){
    sess=req.session; // it has 'auth_token' param in it.
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Storing per-user data in global variables on a server application will almost certainly not work.  This will become a problem if you have multiple users or multiple servers.  (How would you ensure that each user access the correct token from global memory, or even on a machine where that user hasn't had their token stored?)

The whole point of a session cookie is to preserve this state as the client repeatedly contacts the server.  Just use the cookie value for each request to be safe.

Comment: Shouldn’t this variable only live for the time of the api request?

Comment: Then what's the point of it being a global?  Global variables, by definition, live forever.  If you want another scope, then implement just that scope.